# UITextview not showing top lines after rotation to landscape

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have problem when rotate the device/iOS simulator to landscape. The `UITextView` doesn´t show up on top. It's showing in the middle instead until I scroll it up. I have tried many things like :

```
[textView sizeToFit];
[textView layoutIfNeeded];

[textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];

[textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0) animated:NO];
```

I know my question is quite short, but I see no solution out there that´s help.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? if so, Interface Builder, or code? If code, can you show that? If you are just setting up the frames, can you show your code for setting up your view? Also, is your `UITextView` inside of a `UIScrollView`? It sounds that way from your comment about scrolling.

Comment: I have fixed one of text fiedl successfully...buy using : [textView sizeToFit];
But another one could not fix by this code...don´t kneo why.

Comment: Finally I fixed this problem by adding this line  : self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: Do you have constraints from all four sides of your `UITextView` to it's superview? That should be automatically resizing your `UITextView`. `sizeToFit` `layoutIfNeeded` and setting the edges should not be needed. Only the scrolling code.

Comment: Hi, yes I have constraints for all 4 sides. SHound I have less than 4 ?
I tried to put only 2 constraints on top and buttom. It works...but I got yellow tag warning to set the rest.  hmmm works this one but not work for another what should I do ?

Comment: If you just have that one `UITextView`, you've done the right thing. What is the other view, and how are you trying to place it? In the same top-level view? If so, you need to figure out how you want it placed in relation to the `UITextView` and set your constraints between those two views. The constraints and the views all work together to form the layout. They should not be independent of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution I found.
**In Xcode6:**
**Choose Navigation Controller-->On the right panel of interface builder**
-Tick off Adjust Scroll View Inset.

**in .m file in viewDidLoad**
-put this code:
[_myTextViewGrm  sizeToFit];

And also put this method in .m file

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.myTextViewGrm scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
}
```

**DONE !!!!**

Comment: This method is now deprecated, you should use `- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator;` instead.